# After upgrading to R 4.3.3 and Shiny 1.8.0 on ubuntu, I am not able to run shiny. Error in is.call(funBody[[idx]]) && as.character(funBody[[idx]][[1

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny

After upgrading to R 4.3.3 and Shiny 1.8.0 on ubuntu, I am not able to run shiny. Error in is.call(funBody[[idx]]) && as.character(funBody[[idx]][[1]]) == : 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

System details
Output of sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Etc/UTC
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.5.1 shiny_1.8.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] crayon_1.5.2      cli_3.6.2         rlang_1.1.3       stringi_1.8.3     promises_1.2.1    jsonlite_1.8.8    xtable_1.8-4     
 [8] glue_1.7.0        htmltools_0.5.7   httpuv_1.6.14     sass_0.4.8        jquerylib_0.1.4   ellipsis_0.3.2    fastmap_1.1.1    
[15] yaml_2.3.8        lifecycle_1.0.4   memoise_2.0.1     compiler_4.3.3    Rcpp_1.0.12       rstudioapi_0.15.0 later_1.3.2      
[22] digest_0.6.35     R6_2.5.1          magrittr_2.0.3    bslib_0.6.1       tools_4.3.3       withr_3.0.0       mime_0.12        
[29] cachem_1.0.8
```

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
                  titlePanel(title="Title", windowTitle = "Window Title"),br(),
                  tabPanel("",
                           navbarPage("",inverse = T, id="oneClickTabPanel"
                                    
                           )
                  )
)
)


#server.R
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$columnLookupDataFileUi <- renderUI({
        t<-div("OK")
        t
    })
})
```

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4357
Warning: Error in &&: 'length = 3' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
  49: .rs.findBreakpointSteps
  48: .rs.findBreakpointSteps
  47: .rs.findBreakpointSteps
  46: .rs.findBreakpointSteps
  45: .rs.removeBreakpoints
  44: registerShinyDebugHook
  43: registerDebugHook
  42: wrapFunctionLabel
  41: .subset2(x, "impl")$defineOutput
  40: $<-.shinyoutput
  38: server [./server.R#5]
   1: runApp
```

Comment: Better to ask at https://shiny.posit.co/